# MovieTexture won't play audio

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio-player

I'm trying to dynamically load and play a video file. No matter what I do, I cannot seem to figure out why the audio does not play.

```
var www = new WWW("http://unity3d.com/files/docs/sample.ogg");
var movieTexture = www.movie;
var movieAudio = www.movie.audioClip;
while (!movieTexture.isReadyToPlay) yield return 0;

// Assign movie texture and audio
var videoAnimation = videoAnimationPrefab.GetComponent<VideoAnimation>();
var videoRenderer = videoAnimation.GetVideoRenderer();
var audioSource = videoAnimation.GetAudioSource();
videoRenderer.material.mainTexture = movieTexture;
audioSource.clip = movieAudio;

// Play the movie and sound
movieTexture.Play();
audioSource.Play();

// Double check audio is playing...
Debug.Log("Audio playing: " + audioSource.isPlaying);
```

Every time I receive `Audio playing: False`

I've also tried using a GUITexture [using this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MovieTexture-audioClip.html) as a guide, but no dice. There are no errors displayed in the console.

What am I doing wrong that makes the audio never work?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed to:

```
while (!movieTexture.isReadyToPlay) yield return 0;
var movieAudio = movieTexture.audioClip;
```

Even though [`AudioClip`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioClip.html) inherits from `Object`, a call to `movieTexture.audioClip` seems to return a copied version instead of returning a reference by value to the object. So at the time I was assigning it, it had not been created yet and had to wait until the movie was "Ready to Play" until fetching the audioClip.